# Disqus shows wrong url which was set up with PHP

Tags: php, disqus

I am using a php variable to set the `this.page.url` in the `disqus_config` function, like this:

```
$permalink = 'http://example.com/post/2016/my-favorite-post-today';
```

and then i echoed that variable to set the `this.page.url`:

```
this.page.url = '<?php echo($permalink); ?>';
```

I expected the link to my comments on moderate comments menu in admin page to be like the variable above, but instead I found:

```
'http://example.com/post/2016#comment-1234567'
```

which is useless because I can't use that link to find my comment on my post (because `/my-favorite-post-today` part is missing from the link).

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I got from disqus installation instruction (along with other codes of course):

```
var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = String({$permalink});  
        // Desperately using js String() function after countless failed attempt
        this.page.identifier = '<?php echo($row["id"]); ?>';
        this.page.title = '<?php echo($row["title"]); ?>';
 };
```

And here is how I created the permalink var:

```
$permalink = "http://example.com/post/{$request_ary[2]}/{$request_ary[3]}";
```

The `request_ary` array elements is taken from url parameter, example: `/2016/my-post-created-tonight`

Comment: Disqus? You using Wordpress?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, I created a simple blog using php and decided to use Disqus as comment system

Comment: So disqus using which SDK? PHP or JS?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm using Universal Code install. I'll update my question a little bit

Comment: Sure, that'll be great.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can comment on every posts but I can't access my post page from admin page on Disqus because the incorrect url, like shown above

Comment: Oh... Not sure how to solve it. But yea... Let's wait for other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the structure of my blog (so the value of `$permalink` var was also changed) from

```
$permalink = "http://example.com/post/{$request_ary[2]}/{$request_ary[3]}";
```

to

```
$permalink = "http://example.com/blog/{$request_ary[2]}/{$request_ary[3]}";
```

Notice I have changed `post` to `blog` and it now works just fine. I am not sure why but I guess it has something to do with how Disqus handles the javascript string (`this.page.url`) containing word `post`.